# What do electricians and mechanics "do"?

Tags: single-word-requests, analogy

- A carpenter does carpentry.
- A scientist does science.
- An engineer does engineering.
- A blacksmith does blacksmithing.

(The grammar of these sentences may be poor; the point is to get the idea across.)

So then:

- What does an electrician do?
- What does a (car) mechanic do?

Or are there perhaps really no such words?

Comment: Not all vocations have a neat correspondence between the names of the practitioner and the practice.

Comment: @Robusto ok, but does the vocation even have a name in this case? what are the vocations I'm referring to?

Comment: Blacksmiths smith.  So do silversmiths, goldsmiths etc.

Comment: An electrician does electrical work, and a mechanic fixes cars. Also, I wouldn't say "a scientist does science," though I might say "a scientist does scientific work."

Comment: @J.R. It's not so much about filling in the blank in "A scientist does <blank>", but that there is a word for a discipline and a practitioner of that discipline (science, and scientist, respectively). It seems there is no name for the discipline of which electricians are practitioners.

Comment: That's fine - although your question might read a little better if you change those four instances of "does" to "works in the field of".

Comment: @PhilMJones So they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider that an electrician *wires*

> **wire** : *verb* to provide (a building, room, etc.) with wires for a particular service or for electricity

and that a mechanic *repairs*

> **repair** *verb* 1a :  to restore by replacing a part or putting together what is torn or broken :  fix  b :  to restore to a sound or healthy state :  renew

from m-w.com

Comment: The "repair" is pretty generic, I know.

Comment: It sounds like "automobile maintenance/repair" is a good fit for the mechanic. I'm not sure if "wire" is quite adequate for electrician, though, since they do more than that, as far as I know. It feels like there needs to be a word like "electricianism", but I guess none exists.

Answer (score 1):

It's by no means a 'single word', but many automobile mechanics would say that they do "Auto Repair".  Though this of course only refers to the reparations of a vehicle, not the construction of one or the upgrading of one that is not broken.

For the act of working on a vehicle, there is "tuning up", or "bodywork" if you want to refer to only the outer 'body' of the car.

Or you could modify the two, since both individuals are engineers.

You could try 'automotive engineering' or 'electrical engineering', but both of these phrases specifically refer to automotive engineers and electrical engineers, rather than mechanics and electricians, so to avoid confusion, this is only advised if the person's role is already well established by context.

Comment: There is a big difference between what electricians do, and what electrical engineers do. Those are two different careers with distinctly different qualifications.

Comment: @J.R. I was not aware of the difference.  My answer has been corrected.

Comment: That's an improvement, but I think the same is true in the automobile industry. The automotive engineer is designing next year's models. The mechanic is fixing the models from prior years.

Comment: @J.R. you know, that might be the root of the problem here.  The listed individuals who perform "X" are all individuals who produce new products, whereas the two being asked about are repairmen working on products already in place.

Comment: Interesting thought, but... a researcher performs research, a surgeon performs surgery, a doctor practices medicine. A cosmetologist practices cosmetology, but a barber cuts hair. A coach coaches, a judge judges, a runner runs, but do coopers coop, or plumbers plumb? Electricians can lay the wire in a new building, or fix the wiring in an old building, the same way carpenters could be called in to build, repair, or renovate. I think it has more to do with etymology (where did the word come from?) than what the career demands.

Comment: In Br English plumbers *do* plumb - you might well hear someone say 'I plumbed-in a bath today'